# Postgresql - How to Convert all Column Names to Lowercase

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a travel survey with a series of tables (lots and lots of columns) that I exported from MS Access into a postgres database. I've search around a lot for an explanation of how to convert all the column names to lower case, but I haven't been able to successfully apply any of the solutions I've found. I'm relatively new to postgres and would appreciate some step by step explanation if possible.

This link appears to have code for accomplishing this task, but I run into errors when trying to run them in psql or in the pgadmin.

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/141-Lowercasing-table-and-column-names.html

Or there is this:

```
\o /tmp/go_to_lower
select 'ALTER TABLE '||'"'||tablename||'"'||' RENAME TO ' ||
lower(tablename)||';' from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';
psql -U username database < /tmp/go_to_lower
```

it appears to run but then the database still has upper_case columns.

I'd really appreciate some help with this, sorry if this is something simple that I'm just missing.

Many thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64648/discussion-on-question-by-mdgis-postgresql-how-to-convert-all-column-names-to).